# Setting all values within a subsection of a 2D array to another value using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D grid of values.  For example, they might look like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

What I would like to do is set all the 0's that are contained within the 1's to a different value.

Essentially what I want to do is get the first instance of 1 and the last instance of 1 in a row or column, and then any 0's within this boundary I would like to set to another value.

I can brute-force it by getting the first and last instances, and then manually setting it, but is there a numpy-way of doing this more efficiently?

Comment: I don't see a way around brute force. Don't really know my python though :p And swapping all zeroes between the first and last ones in a row/column wouldn't give correct results for all matrices (I'm thinking of cases where there are an uneven number of ones).

Answer (score 1):

Generally `skimage` might have some more algorithms if you do more image stuff. This problem is covered nicely by `scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes`.